# Merge maps if key already exists with two levels

Tags: java, scala

I wrote the following function:

```
private[this] def extractAerospikeBinsFromKafkaConnectorResource(connectors: List[KafkaConnector]): Map[AerospikeNamespace, Map[AerospikeSet, RecoverBins]] = {
    connectors.foldLeft(Map.empty[AerospikeNamespace, Map[AerospikeSet, RecoverBins]]) {
      case (acc, connector) =>
        acc ++
          TopicsConfig
            .parseYaml(connector.getSpec.getConfig.get("config-yaml").toString)
            .topics
            .values
            .map(topicConfig => topicConfig.mapping.namespace.value -> Map(topicConfig.mapping.set.value -> RecoverBins(topicConfig.mapping.bins)))
    }
  }
```

- `acc` is Map[AerospikeNamespace, Map[AerospikeSet, RecoverBins]], for example:

```
Map(namespace -> Map(test-recovery-set-single -> SingleBin))
```

- `TopicsConfig` contains `namespace`, `set` and `List[Bins]` which is logically `Map[Namespace, Map[Set, List[Bins]]`

I want to find a nice way to merge two maps of type `Map[AerospikeNamespace, Map[AerospikeSet, RecoverBins]]` into one, such that if they have same AerospikeNamespace, its will be contacted and if they have same AerospikeNamespace and AerospikeSet its will be contacted, for example:

**input:**

1. Map(namespace -> Map(test-recovery-set-double -> SingleBin))
2. Map(namespace -> Map(test-recovery-set-double -> MultiBin))
3. Map(namespace -> Map(test-recovery-set-multi -> MultiBin))
4. Map(namespace2 -> Map(test-recovery-set-other -> SingleBin))

**output:**

```scala
Map (
namespace -> Map(
        test-recovery-set-double -> List[MultiBin, SingleBin]),
        test-recovery-set-multi -> List[MultiBin]),
),
namespace2 -> Map(test-recovery-set-single -> SingleBin)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Scala 2.13 then this helper function merges a list of `Maps` to a single `Map`:

```
def mergeMaps[T, U](maps: List[Map[T, U]]): Map[T, List[U]] =
  maps
    .flatMap(_.toList) // Convert each map to list and concatenate
    .groupMap(_._1)(_._2) // Group by key to new Map
```

It converts each map to a list of pairs, flattens the list, and then creates a new map by grouping on the first value in the pair and extracting the second value.

Now you just need to apply this to the outer map and then each inner map:

```
val maps = List(
  Map("namespace" -> Map("test-recovery-set-double" -> "SingleBin")),
  Map("namespace" -> Map("test-recovery-set-double" -> "MultiBin")),
  Map("namespace" -> Map("test-recovery-set-multi" -> "MultiBin")),
  Map("namespace2" -> Map("test-recovery-set-other" -> "SingleBin"))
)

mergeMaps(maps).map{ case (k, v) => k -> mergeMaps(v) }
```

The result is

```
Map(namespace2 -> Map(test-recovery-set-other -> List(SingleBin)), namespace -> Map(test-recovery-set-multi -> List(MultiBin), test-recovery-set-double -> List(SingleBin, MultiBin)))
```

Answer (score 2):

The [cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats) library provides this functionality virtually out of the box.

```scala
val maps = List(
  Map("namespace" -> Map("test-recovery-set-double" -> "SingleBin")),
  Map("namespace" -> Map("test-recovery-set-double" -> "MultiBin")),
  Map("namespace" -> Map("test-recovery-set-multi" -> "MultiBin")),
  Map("namespace2" -> Map("test-recovery-set-other" -> "SingleBin"))
)

import cats.implicits._

maps.foldMap(_.view.mapValues(_.view.mapValues(_ :: Nil).toMap).toMap)
/*
Map(
  namespace2 -> Map(
    test-recovery-set-other -> List(SingleBin)
  ),
  namespace -> Map(
    test-recovery-set-multi -> List(MultiBin),
    test-recovery-set-double -> List(SingleBin, MultiBin)
  )
)
*/
```

`foldMap` works by wrapping the inner values of your maps in a `List` and then folding them into a single `Map` by using the [`Monoid`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/kernel/Monoid.html) instance of `Map[A, Map[B, List[C]]]`.

The only less elegant part of this code comes from `mapValues` in scala 2.13 being awkward to use.

Instead of using `foldMap`, it's not hard to implement yourself:

```scala
import cats.implicits._

val listMaps = maps.map(_.view.mapValues(_.view.mapValues(_ :: Nil).toMap).toMap)
listMaps.reduce(_ |+| _) // |+| is an alias for Monoid.combine
```

As pointed out in the comments by @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, you can also clean up the `mapValues` a bit with some more cats magic.

```scala
maps.foldMap(_.fmap(_.fmap(_ :: Nil)))
// or
maps.foldMap(_.nested.map(_ :: Nil).value)
```

Comment: If you have **cats**, you can call `fmap` on a `Map` to imitate `mapValues` - Also, recent versions of **cats** only need `import cats.syntax.all._`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Cool, thanks! I hadn't thought of using `fmap` on `Map`. You can also use `_.nested.map`.